# WebStorm: "Element is not Exported" error

Tags: javascript, webstorm

So I know I could get down voted on this because I have already been searching how to fix this problem and have found that it has been asked before and it seems a lot of people are having the problem, but nothing that I have found has helped me resolve my own problem.

I am trying to `fetch()` content using an API using a `Request()` object like so (this is just an example and probably doesn't run so no need to try to run it):

```
var request = new Request('https://secure.realcove.com/api.php');

fetch(request).then(function (response) {
    return response.json().then(function (json) {
        console.log(json.name);
    });
});
```

[image: The warning I get on Request()][image: Wants me to define fetch()]

So I'm not sure what to do because I can't even use `Request` the way I want to because it seems that WebStorm has a conflict and thinks it is something other than what I need it for.

Any advice or thoughts on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. All that I have tried so far has not worked.

```
WebStorm 2017.1
Build #WS-171.3780.79 
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b13 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.5
```

And I know my JS is running ECMAScript 5.1 if that matters.  Here is the link for the Documentation of Request if it is needed : [Request - Web APIs| MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there are no TypeScript stubs available for fetch API.
I can suggest the following: use `npm install whatwg-fetch` or `bower install fetch` to install [fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) somewhere (in your project, or to some different location), then include the downloaded `fetch.js` as a library in your project:

[image]

this works fine for me

[image]

Comment: Okay, I will give that a shot. Thanks for the help!